# Given an array with 2 integers that repeat themselves the same no. of times, how do i print the two integers

Tags: java, arrays

i'm new to this, Say if you typed 6 6 6 1 4 4 4 in the command line, my code gives the most frequent as only 6 and i need it to print out 6 and 4 and i feel that there should be another loop in my code

```
public class MostFrequent {

  //this method creates an array that calculates the length of an integer typed and returns 
  //the maximum integer...
  public static int freq(final int[] n) {
    int maxKey = 0;
    //initiates the count to zero
    int maxCounts = 0;

    //creates the array...
    int[] counts = new int[n.length];

    for (int i=0; i < n.length; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j < n[i].length; j++)
        counts[n[i][j]]++;
        if (maxCounts < counts[n[i]]) {
            maxCounts = counts[n[i]];
            maxKey = n[i];
        }
    }
    return maxKey;
}
//method mainly get the argument from the user
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int len = args.length;

    if (len == 0) {
      //System.out.println("Usage: java MostFrequent n1 n2 n3 ...");
      return;
    } 

    int[] n = new int[len + 1];

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
      n[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    } 

    System.out.println("Most frequent is "+freq(n));
} 
}
```

Thanks...`enter code here`

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: Yes but I've done most of it but i've been trying to figure this out for 2 days and its due around 6 in the morning....

Comment: OK, here we go. First, Why two indices: `counts[n[i][j]]++;`?

Comment: It seems you are trying to use counting sort. Am I right?

Comment: Yes...sorry but i was experimenting a little bit with that and the second loop...

Answer (score 0):

Though this may not be a complete solution, it's a suggestion. If you want to return more than one value, your method should return an array, or better yet, an ArrayList (because you don't know how many frequent numbers there will be). In the method, you can add to the list every number that is the most frequest.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> freq(final int[] n) {
     ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
     ...

     if (something)
         list.add(thatMostFrequentNumber)

     return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions looks like this:

```
    // To use count sort the length of the array need to be at least as
    // large as the maximum number in the list.
    int[] counts = new int[MAX_NUM]; 
    for (int i=0; i < n.length; i++)
        counts[n[i]]++;

    // If your need more than one value return a collection
    ArrayList<Integer> mf = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0;  i < MAX_NUM; i++)
        if (counts[i] > max)
            max = counts[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++)
        if (counts[i] == max)
            mf.add(i);

    return mf;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just do this easily by using the HashTable class.

Part 1. Figure out the frequency of each number.

You can do this by either a HashTable or just a simple array if your numbers are whole numbrs and have a decent enough upper limit.

Part 2. Find duplicate frequencies.

You can just do a simple for loop to figure out which numbers are repeated more than once and then print them accordingly. This wont necessarily give them to you in order though so you can store the information in the first pass and then print it out accordingly. You can use a `HashTable<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>` for this. Use the key to store frequency and the ArrayList to store the numbers that fall within that frequency.

You can maintain a "max" here while inserting into our HashTable if you only want to print out only the things with most frequency.

---

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different way to handle this.  First you sort the list, then loop through and keep track of the largest numbers:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int n[] = { 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 1 };
        List<Integer> maxNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Integer lastValue = null;
        int currentCount = 0;
        Arrays.sort(n);
        for( int i : n ){
            if( lastValue == null ||  i != lastValue ){
                if( currentCount == max ){
                    maxNums.add(lastValue);
                }
                else if( currentCount > max ){
                    maxNums.clear();
                    maxNums.add(lastValue);
                    max = currentCount;
                }
                lastValue = i;
                currentCount = 1;
            }
            else {
                currentCount++;
            }
            System.out.println("i=" + i + ", currentCount=" + currentCount);
        }
        if( currentCount == max ){
            maxNums.add(lastValue);
        }
        else if( currentCount >= max ){
            maxNums.clear();
            maxNums.add(lastValue);
        }

        System.out.println(maxNums);
    }
}
```

You can try it at:  http://ideone.com/UbmoZ5